# 401 Unauthorized in post man

Tags: azure

I have azure push notification hub and azure web API. i am using api key to authorize this.

**POST method**

http://appname.azurewebsites.net/api/notifications/requests

**BODY**
{
"action": "action_b",
"silent": true
}

apikey added in header.

I am getting 401 Unauthorized issue in post man and swagger also tried. i am getting same error.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have fixed this my self. i have repair my VS and reinstall my windows iis. then it fixed. my localhost also not worked before this. now fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this my self. i have repair my VS and reinstall my windows iis. then it fixed.